# How to increase "zoom out" speed in a pinch gesture handler where the scale ranges 0 - 1 for zooming out but 1 - n for zooming in?

Tags: javascript, zooming, formula, pinchzoom, react-native-gesture-handler

I am developing a mobile app and have an issue with a zooming feature. I am using the React Native [`PinchGestureHandler`](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/handler-pinch.html). It provides a `scale` parameter, which is defined as:

> The scale factor relative to the points of the two touches in screen coordinates

Which means: As further away the two fingers go as larger the scale factor becomes. Now let's assume I have an object that is zoomed into using this `scale` factor. Let's also assume the user wanted to zoom in quite far and stops zooming at a scale factor of `5`. Now I am storing the scale range in a state (in this case `prevScaleRange = 4`, because of `5 - 1` or `lastScaleFactor - inititalScaleFactor`) so that for the next pinch event it does not start from a scale of `1` but with the current visible scale factor of `5` using this formula:

```
newScale = event.nativeEvent.scale + prevScaleRange
```

However, when zooming out the scale factor of the event again starts at `1`, which means the (theoretical) range of the scale factor is `1` (from `1` to `0`). But in the "zoom in" case the range was `4`. Therefore, when I now zoom out with the above formula, the user needs at least four pinch events to reach the very first case of `prevScaleRange = 0`.

Somehow I cannot get my head around finding a formula for how to adjust the scale factor for zooming out in a way that the zoom out event has the same speed as the zoom in event. Can anybody help out?

Answer (score 1):

Since when zooming in the scale factor goes from 1 to 4 and when zooming out it goes from 1 to 0, we can rescale the scale factor values only when zooming out so instead of going from 1 to 0, it goes from 1 to -4 (can be adjusted).

Referring to this formula: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/190619

```js
// Pinch event scale factor
const scaleFactor = e.scale 

if (scaleFactor < 1) {
  const OLD_MAX = 1
  const OLD_MIN = 0

  const NEW_MAX = 1
  const NEW_MIN = -4

  const newScale = ((NEW_MAX - NEW_MIN) / (OLD_MAX - OLD_MIN)) * (scaleFactor - OLD_MAX) + NEW_MAX
}
```